# Android device as a microphone via usb cable

Tags: microphone

I was wandering how can I connect my android device to my Ubuntu 14.04 using usb cable and use the android device as a microphone.
Any suggestions?

Comment: you can install something like ipwebcam which uses wifi or droidcam which I believe uses usb

Comment: I know i can use droidcam, but I just need something to use my android as a mic for my ubuntu

Comment: I have same problem. if you find any solution pls write one answer or comment for this question